# Программирование под Linux

Tags: c++, linux, книги

Не так давно я начал изучать C/C++, сейчас я уже достаточно хорошо себя в нём чувствую и хотелось бы уже поработать с ОС, а именно с Linux. С самим Linux я знаком не сильно, но по ходу обучения буду осваивать систему с точки зрения программиста. Сейчас стоит Ubuntu, поставил g++, исходники компилируются, всё хорошо. Основной упор делается на системное и сетевое ПО. Собственно нужна литература на русском, т.к англйиский не на уровне чтобы учить программирование к сожалению, нужно что нибудь для новичков.

Выбор велик, не хотелось бы читать плохую литературу.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вряд ли этот вопрос относится к C++ (не взирая на тэг).

Comment: @avp возможно, я ошибся. К чему вопрос относится? Может, выделить отдельный вопрос с литературой по разработке Linux и под Linux?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, к программированию (разработке) в \*nix с использованием системных вызовов. Если мы делаем общие вопросы со  списками литературы и есть дубликаты, то может стоит их объединить?

Comment: @avp конечно, стоит сделать новый вопрос, отметить общим, а к нему прицепить остальные. Может быть, вы захотите составить хорошую подборку литературы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала могу порекомендовать очень хорошую книгу Метью, Стоунс "Основы программирования в Linux". С нуля обо всем в достаточно приличном объеме. Для начала самое пригодное.

Answer (score 4):

Так как Вы написали, что "упор делается на системное и сетевое ПО", не могу не посоветовать классику: Стивенс, Раго, "UNIX: Профессиональное программирование", Стивенс, "UNIX: Разработка сетевых приложений", Стивенс, "UNIX: Взаимодействие процессов".
Последние две на самом деле два тома одной книги, материал "Взаимодействия процессов" подразумевает, что читатель знаком с "Разработкой сетевых приложений".

Написано довольно подробно и доступно, простота изложение - это вообще визитная карточка Рика Стивенса. Есть переиздание "Разработки сетевых приложений" с тремя авторами - попытка переписать некоторые разделы, рассказав о новых API. Написано чуть хуже, правилось уже без Стивенса, к сожалению, он скончался в 1999 году,

Answer (score 1):

Очень хорошо и понятно изложено у  [Теренс Чан - Системное программирование на С++ для  Unix](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/88398/)

Answer (score 1):

Уже после задания вопроса появилась хорошая книжка Роберта Лава:

[Linux. Системное программирование](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/26420096/).